# Can defaultdict accept callables dependent on the given missing key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

The examples given in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) all seem to be the cases where the first callable argument in `defaultdict` is a "constant" function, like `int`, `list`, or `lambda: const` etc. I don't know if `defaultdict` is just supposed to take constant functions as its callabe argument, but if not, I want the callable to be dependent on the missing key values I give. For example

```
toy = collections.defaultdict(lambda x: len(x), {'foo': 3})
toy['barr']
```

What I expect is whenever I give a missing key string, for example `'barr'`, the container can create a new entry with `'barr'` being the key and its length `4` being the value. But it doesn't work. Instead, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I expected `'barr'` to be this `lambda`'s argument here, but it was apparently not the case. So what could have gone wrong?

Comment: `defaultdict` is designed for default values, that is to say values that don't rely on their keys.  You're best off just using a regular `dict` and doing it yourself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default factory is never given any arguments, so you can't do it like that. What you can do, though, is subclass `defaultdict` and define the `__missing__` method:

```
class CustomDefaultDict(collections.defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = value = len(key)
        return value
```

To make it more easily-extendible, you could also take advantage of the `default_factory`, but give it the key as an argument:

```
class CustomDefaultDict(collections.defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError((key,))
        self[key] = value = self.default_factory(key)
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

---

If default_factory is not None, it is called **without arguments** to provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned.

---

The `defaultdict` simply doesn't work the way you are trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand now: so basically `defaultdict` is really just supposed to take constant functions as callable arg. It is a bit strange though: why use a constant *function* instead of just the constant itself?

Comment: Because it's the more typical use case.

Comment: To be clear: the intent is for defaultdict to act like a regular dict that has a specified `setdefault` argument. The `setdefault` method only accepts a function that does not accept arguments.

Comment: A constant instead of a constant function would break if the constant is mutable, and modifying the value in one entry of the defaultdict would modify it for all entries.